# How to set cookie for a domain after redirecting it to login of your domain (like login via google)

Tags: redirect, cookies

What happens in stackoverflow login is that when I click on login with google then the page redirects to google, there I login and I return back to stack overflow being logged in, and a cookie is set on stackoverflow itself by google I guess.

So, I want to know how could a domain(stackoverflow in the above case) store a cookie from **my platform's** login(google login in the above case) and get back to it.

Is there a plugin or something for it ? Need Guidance.